# How to assign specific cpu num to each process in python Multiprocessing?

Tags: multiprocessing, python-3.6

I run two processes with Multiprocessing in python like

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
pool = Pool(processes=2)
pool.apply_async(func1, (args))
pool.apply_async(func2, (args))
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

func1() and func2() are indepedent most of time and interact with files sometime. func1() needs more resources(cpu nums) and func2 needs less. So I want to assign more cpu to func1 process and less to func2 process. However, I read the [multiprocessing doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html) and cannot find the option to set cpu num to each process.

Is there any good solutions?

Another question: how to monitor how much cpu num each process use? Does multiprocessing assign cpu num equally, like 50-50, 33-33-33, 25-25-25-25?

Comment: "Is there any good solutions?" not in python. This is a very OS dependent behavior as well... on windows you'd be looking for something like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setprocessaffinitymask). I think you also may be confused a bit about how multiprocessing works in this case: each process strictly runs on one core at a time no matter what. The only exception to this is if you use libraries that use multithreading and release the GIL, in which case the OS will handle the load based on it's scheduling algorithm

Comment: Getting things like current cpu usage (and memory usage) is typically done with the `psutil` library